# Route not working on refreshing the page in react deployed application

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, react-router-dom

i am currently facing an issue where i just hosted my react application on Netify(web hosting website)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ6mc.png)
the above pic show the code i used to route them, now when i refresh the page it show "Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site."
i am not sure why it showing this i deployed the application on github too but same thing happened there too please help.?

i am expecting that route will start working properly and if i refresh the page  it will reload the page at that route.